# Equality of morphism of representations of $S_n$ and $A_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group and $A_n$ the Alternating group.

Let $(V,\rho)$ be a simple representation of $S_n$.

Let $(W,\pi)$ be a simple representation of $A_n$.

Suppose $V=W$. I saw in some proof that for $x\in A_n: \rho(x) = \pi(x)$.

Is that correct? I can't see why they must be equal for $x\in A_n$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by $V=W$?

Comment: I mean that the vector spaces of the representations are equal: $\rho: S_n\to GL(V)$ and $\pi: A_n\to GL(W=V)$

Comment: Does "simple" mean irreducible? Does $V = W$ mean only that they have the same dimension? Does $\rho(x)
= \pi(x)$ mean that the representations are conjugate (asking for equality doesn't really make sense?

Comment: With the most natural interpretation of the question the answer is on: $A_7$ has $2$ absolutely irreducible representations of dimension $14$,  $W_1$ and $W_2$. Both of these extend to representations $V_1$ and $V_2$ of $S_7$, which are unique up to twisting by the sign character. But if $V = V_1$ as a representation of $S_7$ and $W = W_2$ as a representation of $A_7$ then the answer is no, because $W_1$ and $W_2$ are distinct representations of $A_7$.

Comment: (Something similar happens with a pair of $5$-dimensional representations of $A_6$ and four corresponding representations of $S_6$. But in this case, the $5$-dimensional representations of $A_6$ are at least permuted by the outer automorphism of $S_6$.)

Comment: @user655377 Yes simple means irreducible, is it relevant terminology? When I say $V=W$ I mean $V=W$, same dimension and same space, like $V=W=\Bbb C^*$ for instance

Comment: @user655377 By $\rho(x) = \pi(x)$ I mean literally for each $x\in A_n, \rho(x) = \pi(x)$

Comment: @user655377 Thank you for your counter example. But here we would need V=W right? which is not the case if I follow you?

Comment: Since $V$ and $W$ have extra structure, saying $V = W$ is very ambigious. If $V$ and $W$ have the same dimension then $V \simeq W$ as vector spaces, and so you can make $S_7$ act on $V=V_1$ via the representation $V_1$, then fix an isomorphism of vector spaces $W_2 \simeq V$, and then let $A_7$ act on $V$ via the isomorphism as vector spaces with $W_2$.

Comment: If you are not even allowing "up to conjugation" then there are much more trivial examples. If $(W,\pi)$ is an irreducible representation of $A_n$, then so is $(W,\pi') := (W,A \pi A^{-1})$ for any invertible matrix $A$. Since for generic $A$ and $x \in A_n$ we have $\pi'(x) \ne \pi(x)$ the claim cannot possibly be true in this sense.